# pytest 3.4.2 test py code has to be written in the respective application code python version only?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pytest

We are using python 2.7.4 in our project application code and planning to use pytest 3.4.2 version for unit testing. In future we might upgrade our application code to latest python 3.6.X.

Given that pytest 3.4.X supports both python 2.7 and > 3.3 versions, the test code files ( Example: test_mymodule.py) has to be written in any python version or it has to be written on the python version used for the application code.

To exactly pin point the question,

Application code with python 2.7.x version --> the corresponding test code with pytest has to be written in 2.7.x compatible code or it can even be written with python 3.4 version compatible code?. Will pytest understand the test code accordingly and run the test files?.

Comment: You should always aim to write compatible Python 2 code.

Comment: thanks erip. I don't see it explicitly documented anywhere in pytest.org. If you are aware of any such doc, please point it to me. It will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to test your code in Python 2.7 - you will run your test code which will import your application code and call it. That all happens in the same interpreter.

Therefore for your test code to test Python 2.7 code it will need to run under the Python 2.7 interpreter - i.e. your test code will need to be Python 2.7 compatible code itself.

You could have two versions of your test code - but I would recommend using something like 'six'. The six package has a lot of functions and methods which mean that you can write one code base, and when that code runs, and calls the six library it can determine how to call that particular functionality. As much as possible try to have a single test code base for all Python versions (especially if your application does the same thing under all versions).

I would also recommend making use of **futures_** so that your Python code has access to as many Python 3 features as it can.

Many of the useful Python 3 features (like the mock library have been backported to Python 2 - for instance, if you decided to use 'six' then your code can do this :

```
if six.PY2:
     import mock
else:
     from unittest import mock
```

And always get the right mock library.

And finally - this is a perfect example of where to use virtual environments; you have a specific virtual env for your Python 2 testing - where you install just those libraries you need to test under Python 2 (including backports like mock if you need them); then later when you come to test Python 3 - you run the Python 3 code with potentially a different set of libraries).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the pointers. I wasn't aware of the "six" utility. I will explore it.

Comment: Feel free to upvote or accept this answer if it is useful - thanks